# Azure Data Factory - CSV to Parquet - Changing file extension

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have created a Data Factory to convert a CSV file to Parquet format, as I needed to retain the orginial file name I am using the 'Preserve Hierarchy' at the pipeline. The conversion works fine but the output file is generated with the csv extension (an expected output). Is there any out of the box option I could use to generate the file name without the csv extension. I scanned through the system varaible currently supported by ADF and it doesn't list Input File name as an option to mask the file extension - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables. Is writing a custom component the only option?

Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [get metadata activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity) to get the file name of your source dataset and then pass it to both input and output dataset of your copy activity if you are using azure data factory v2.